# MySql table disappears at random after multiple TRUNCATE queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, truncate

I have a dozen of tables that get emptied with TRUNCATE table every 10-20 seconds or so with my php script running in shell from XAMPP local machine.

For unknown reason, every couple hours a random table disappears and as a result my script stops. There are not queries in the script that would drop/delete the table

Whats interesting, is that the table gets deleted in main view, but I still can see it in the sidebar on the left.

When I try to recreate the deleted table, I get "no such table" mysql error. The way I managed to recreate it is by copying table ".frm" file from identical table, it would allow me to drop the old one via sql and recreate it again.

Did anyone ever encountered such behaviour or knows the explanation? This been driving me nuts for the past few days...

Comment: "a random table disappears " - nothing happens at random. There is always a root cause.

Comment: @MitchWheat What I mean by "a random table disappears " is that every time it is a different table that disappears despite the fact that all tables use the same exact function to do the queries. I have them numbered and every time its a random number, so there is no easy pattern to spot "the root case"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should consider not using `truncate` for this kind of operation. Quoting from [the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html):

> Logically, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to a `DELETE` statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements. To achieve high performance, it bypasses the DML method of deleting data. [...] Although `TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to `DELETE`, it is classified as a **DDL statement** rather than a DML statement. It differs from DELETE in the following ways in MySQL 5.5:
>
> - Truncate operations **drop and re-create** the table, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.

This maybe a good thing for non-frequent operations. But you are truncating tables *every 10-20 seconds*! I don't know if your script is running continuously, but if that's the case, there's always a chance that a part of your program is trying to insert a row into a just truncated table (which may have not been completely rebuilt). There are lots of things in my head (and in my gut) that tell me that it's not a good idea to truncate tables so frequently.

On the other hand... Why on earth do you need to truncate tables every 20 seconds!? I can only recommend you avoid doing that... create partitions, index your tables, truncate your tables when you're sure that no other process is trying to use them... Use `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`... `TRUNCATE` is meant for maintenance tasks, not for day-to-day operation (that's my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for such a great a detailed answer, I didn't know that drop and truncate share the same technique, I believe this is what causing the problem. The reason I am emptying table every few seconds is because it is used by other php script to store entire webpages in every row, sizes of those tables quickly jump into gigabytes  and make it impossible to process that amount of data, so I am forced to empty and parse that data as fast as I can. One question, If I use delete instead and another scripts writes to same table at the same time - what will happen in that scenario?

Comment: @Acidon The usual tip: Have a copy of the reference manual at hand (and if you find this answer useful, up-vote it and/or accept it if you want). As for your second question, it depends on your particular implementation (in other words, it is unanswarable without digging into details). Try it, test it... there's no way to tell beforehand.

Comment: Got it, I thought so too, thanks a lot!

Comment: ahh works a charm with Delete, no noticeable change in speed at all for operations with just a few rows like in my case :) you are the man!